# Getting an error 'undefined reference to MainWindow'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to write a function that allows my character in game to go north if there is a valid exit there. When I run the program it gives me this error. I wrote the function in ZorkUL.cpp and included the ZorkUL header file in mainwindow aswell

`` undefined reference to `MainWindow::go(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' ``

This is my code. Any help would be appreciated thanks

ZorkUL.h

```
#define ZORKUL_H_

#include "Command.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include "item.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ZorkUL {
private:
    Parser parser;
    Room *currentRoom;
    void createRooms();

    bool processCommand(Command command);
    void printHelp();
    void goRoom(Command command);
    void createItems();
    void displayItems();
    //string go(string direction);

public:
    ZorkUL();
    void play();
    string printWelcome();
    string go(string direction);
};



#endif /*ZORKUL_H_*/
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include "ZorkUL.h"
#include "Command.h"
#include "CommandWords.h"
#include "Parser.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_northButton_clicked()
{
go("north");
ui->textBox->setText("You went north! You're now in room ");
}
```

Mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QListWidget>
#include "ZorkUL.h"
#include "Character.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();



private:
    void go(string direction);
    void goRoom(string direction);

private slots:
    void on_quitButton_clicked() {
        close();

    };

    void on_northButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

ZorkUL.cpp

````
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#include "ZorkUL.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"


ZorkUL::ZorkUL() {
    createRooms();
}

void ZorkUL::createRooms()  {
    Room *a, *b, *c, *d, *e, *f, *g, *h, *i, *j, *k, *l;

    a = new Room("a");
        a->addItem(new Item("sword", 1, 11));
        a->addItem(new Item("bow", 2, 22));
        a->addItem(new Item("axe", 2, 22));
    b = new Room("b");
    c = new Room("c");
    d = new Room("d");
    e = new Room("e");
    f = new Room("f");
    g = new Room("g");
        g->addItem(new Item("wand", 1, 1));
        g->addItem(new Item("armour" ,1,1));
    h = new Room("h");
    i = new Room("i");
    j = new Room("j");
    k = new Room("k");
    l = new Room("l");

//             (N, E, S, W)
    a->setExits(b, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    b->setExits(NULL, c, NULL, j);
    c->setExits(d, NULL, NULL, b);
    d->setExits(e, NULL, c, NULL);
    e->setExits(NULL, f, d, NULL);
    f->setExits(k, e, g, h);
    g->setExits(f, NULL, NULL, f);
    h->setExits(NULL, f, i, NULL);
    i->setExits(h,NULL, j, NULL);
    j->setExits(i, NULL, NULL, b);
    k->setExits(l, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    l->setExits(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);



        currentRoom = a;
}

string ZorkUL::go(string direction) {
    //Make the direction lowercase
    //transform(direction.begin(), direction.end(), direction.begin(),:: tolower);
    //Move to the next room
    Room* nextRoom = currentRoom->nextRoom(direction);
    if (nextRoom == NULL)
        return("direction null");
    else
    {
        currentRoom = nextRoom;
        return currentRoom->longDescription();
    }
} ```
````

Comment: I don't see a definition of `MainWindow::go` anywhere. That's what the error is complaining about.

Comment: you have included ZorlUL.cpp in your pro-file?

Comment: Your linker is  not complaining about `ZorkUL::go()` its complaining about `MainWindow::go()`. You can't define a go function in some other class and have it work.

Comment: Do I need to define the go function in MainWindow.cpp?

Comment: Yes it must be a member of MainWindow class not `ZorkUL` whatever that is. It's not clear why `ZorkUL` is used at all.

Comment: @killuabusher You need to define it *somewhere*. You've defined `ZorkUL::go`, but not `MainWindow::go`.

Comment: I defined it within Mainwindow.cpp and it gave me errors saying that currentRoom is an undeclared identifier. I also tried it in ZorkUL.cpp and it gives the same errors? I don't know how because it doesn't give that error for the ZorkUL::go(string direction)

Comment: The new error is correct. `MainWindow` has no `currentRoom` member. I think if you showed what you are doing with `ZorkUL` you may be able to get better help.

Comment: I will edit it to show the full ZorkUL file

Comment: You need to add the header as well.

Comment: Your MainWindow probably needs a `ZorkUL` member variable.

Comment: ZorkUL.cpp probably should not include mainwindow.h

Comment: I put ZorkUL.h up there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231071/discussion-between-killuabusher-and-drescherjm).